# Evaluate memory throughput

Tags: memory, performance, motherboard

I use memtest86+ since years to evaluate memory throughput, allowing me to be sure everything is ok before putting a server in action.

With one motherboard I can't have this information:
[image]
The throughput should be just under L3 Cache throughput. But this remain blank.

I used [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) v4.20
I then downloaded v5.01 Also tested with F1 (safe mode) and F2 (multicore)
I also tested [memtest86](http://memtest86.com/) (without the '+')

motherboard : Supermicro H8DG6-F
CPU : 2 x AMD 6272 (2 x 16 cores)
memory : 2 x 8 = 16 Gib ECC memory PC3-12800 (but I will install 8 x 8 = 64 Gib)

I [reported](http://forum.canardpc.com/threads/97415-No-throughput-displayed) the problem in the official forum, but no answer. So I'd like to use another tool.
Anyone knows a tool to evaluate memory throughput?
No operating system is currently installed.

Comment: As i understand your statements, this really shouldn't vary. DDR3 "throughput" should be a constant based on your SPD configuration. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#DDR3_Serial_Presence_Detect  Otherwise please define "Throughput" as you are using it.

Comment: Try a Linux Live CD, rescue Live CD, or the utility partition if there is one installed by default on that computer

Comment: Have you tried swapping the motherboard or the memory module?

Comment: Other software would rely on the same outputs from the hardware as memtest86. You should let SuperMicro deal with this if the board is covered under warranty. If not, I'd start by flashing the BIOS (see their warnings,) testing again with the most current version, then rolling it back to an older version. Be sure you're using compatible memory, and that the modules installed are in the correct locations for the number of modules used. Beyond that, return it if possible, or toss it if you can verify that other boards of the same model do not exhibit the same behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try other products to find if they can do better on your motherboard.

The Advanced Memory Test, part of the [PassMark PerformanceTest](http://www.passmark.com/products/pt.htm) suite
(free 30 day evaluation, then US$27.00 to purchase),
tests several factors which affect the speed of which data is accessed in PC memory.
PassMark is the same company that created MemTest86.

[image: passmark]

Other commercial alternative, available as shareware, is [GoldMemory](http://www.goldmemory.cz/) ($29) :

[image: GoldMemory]

<sub>(I have no personal experience with any of these products.)</sub>